Airflow SparkSubmitOperator can't find spark script path
I'm using Airflow apache/airflow:2.9.1 and spark bitnami/spark:3.5.3 in a docker compose and created a dag that uses SparkSubmitOperator operator to run a spark job.
SparkSubmitOperator operator configured as following:
python_job = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id="python_job",
    conn_id="spark-conn",
    application="jobs/wordcountjob.py",
    env_vars={
            'YARN_CONF_DIR': '/opt/bitnami/spark/yarn'  # Set this if using Yarn
        },
    dag=dag
)

the jobs dir is mounted to both airflow and spark containers to /opt/airflow/jobs path
I use simple spark job wordcountjob.py, I have put it under jobs dir. however when trying to run the dag, I always got this error:
[2024-09-27, 13:03:13 UTC] {spark_submit.py:204} INFO - Could not load connection string spark-conn, defaulting to yarn
[2024-09-27, 13:03:13 UTC] {spark_submit.py:335} INFO - Spark-Submit cmd: spark-submit --master yarn --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.YARN_CONF_DIR=/opt/bitnami/spark/yarn --name arrow-spark /opt/***/jobs/wordcountjob.py
[2024-09-27, 13:03:13 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - /home/***/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyspark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 68: ps: command not found
[2024-09-27, 13:03:18 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - python3: can't open file '/opt/***/jobs/wordcountjob.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[2024-09-27, 13:03:18 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/09/27 13:03:18 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
[2024-09-27, 13:03:18 UTC] {spark_submit.py:488} INFO - 24/09/27 13:03:18 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-76f9f159-d669-4871-bae7-012288312967

seems that it can't find wordcountjob.py. my question is where it's expected to find this script in spark or airflow container? anyway it's existing in both of them and still can't find it!!
